# Having trouble with my Firefox shadows from GTK3 theme

Tags: firefox, themes, gtk3

I customized my GTK 3 theme, but Firefox does not show the window border from the theme. What could be the problem? Sorry for the stupid question, but I’m not sure how to resolve this:

[image: You can see this here]

I think I missed something, the firefox window has a standard box-shadow(original from Whitesur), but the outline from the GTK 3 theme, which I have customized.

[image: The box-shadow of Focused window]

The theme is Whitesur. Here the part of _common.scss, which I have customized:
 [My customized part of code](https://pastebin.com/GixF5MEV)

Here is the full _common.scss:
 [Full _common.scss](https://pastebin.com/BLzExasb)

I haven't changed anything else. If you need more information - ask, I don't know what else to add.

Comment: You may need to provide details on what you did to customize the theme before anyone can start thinking about the origin of the problem.

Comment: Does this border / shadow inconsistency appear when you use the original unmodified Whitesur theme as well?

Comment: Firefox cannot be customised with gtk theme, because it is not csd window. Gonna find another way to do it. May be someone knows the right way?